# How to condense a file: uniq occurences and sum another field

Tags: math, uniq

I have a very large file that looks something like this:

1,22,A
2,10,A
3,4,B
4,3,B
5,20,B

The second column tells me how many instances of the third column there are. So I want to collapse the third column (so that it is effectively uniqued), but add up the second column values. Desired output would be something like:

32,A
27,B

I can come up with some rather complicated ways to do this, but it seems like it ought to be rather simple...

Comment: After researching more, I was able to modify another entry, and used the following to generate the desired output:  
awk '{counts[$3]++; totals[$3] +=$2;} END {for (x in counts) {print x, totals [x];}}'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of "math" answer you would expect...

Given you have a file `input.txt` with the following content:

```
1,22,A
2,10,A
3,4,B
4,3,B
5,20,B
```

Create a new file with the following script in Ruby, put in the same directory as your `input.txt`, and run `ruby script.rb` from the console:

```
File.open('output.txt', 'w+') do |file|
  result = {}

  File.readlines("input.txt").each do |line|
    values = line.split(',')

    letter       = values[2]
    letter_value = values[1].to_i

    result[letter] ||= 0
    result[letter] += letter_value
  end

  result.each do |letter, value|
    file << [value, letter].join(', ')
  end
end
```

Then, look for your result in `output.txt` in the same directory.

Comment: OK, I tried that, but no output.txt file was created. Also, no error messages. I'm completely unfamiliar with Ruby, so I have no idea how to trouble shoot this one.

Comment: I just fixed the script to leave the `output.txt` files in the same folder.